# Asserting a IOException in Junit 5 test

Tags: java, junit5, ioexception

I'm trying to write a Junit 5 test for a method with an IOException. Here's the code:

```
public class PdfUtil {
public void pdfDocument(File pdf) {
    Long pdfFileSize = null;
    try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdf)) {

    pdfFileSize = pdf.length() / 1024;
    PDDocument document = convertPdfToImages(document);
    removeMetadata(document);

    document.save(pdf);
    document.close();

}
catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
} finally {
    logger.info(String.format("someText", pdf.getName(), pdfFileSize, pdf.length() / 1024));
}
}
}
```

And here is the test:

```
@Test
void pdfDocument() throws IOException {
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("testPdf.pdf");
    File pdf = resource.getFile();

assertThrows(IOException.class,
        () -> pdfUtil.pdfDocument(pdf));
}
```

I'm trying to catch an IOException, but so far I got `Expected java.io.IOException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown`. Do you have any suggestions on how to catch it?

Comment: Is your `pdfDocument()` method supposed to throw an `IOException`?

Comment: You've coded `PdfUtil#pdfDocument(File)` to specifically never throw `IOException` by catching it, logging it, and then not rethrowing it. It also doesn't have a `throws IOException` clause, and so could never throw one anyway (`IOException` is a _checked_ exception).

Comment: I approached the problem in the wrong way, thanks for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 3):

There's a design error in your code which makes it impossible to properly test. (Or use). It's this part:

> ```java
> catch (IOException e) {
>    logger.error(e.getMessage());
> } finally {
>    logger.info(String.format("someText", pdf.getName(), pdfFileSize, pdf.length() / 1024));
> }
> ```

This is an anti-pattern. When a problem occurs, you log it, and then **keep right on going**. The code that called this method cannot tell that it failed, which is, naturally, why you can't test what it does when an IOException failure occurs. Think about it: If you ask your computer to install something, and the installer goes: "Okay! Installation succesful!", when the logs of that installer (as if you're going to look at those) actually contain an error, that's highly suspicious behaviour. If you ask a friend to go pick up the groceries for you, they go out, then return back home, and tell you nothing, even though they got no groceries because the store was closed, that's incredibly annoying.

If you catch an exception **you have to handle it**. Logging it does not count.

Often, exceptions cannot be handled. Take this very method: What could you possibly do?

Thus, one trivial solution is simply not to catch it. Leave that to the caller. Of course, the (checked) exceptions your method throws are part of the *what* and not the *how*: They are part of your signature. Hence, any checked exception that the *how* (the body of the method) throws, which isn't an intrinsic part of the *what*, generally shouldn't be thrown out of the method. In these cases, 'catch it and log' it is **still** wrong. Instead, catch it, and **rethrow it**. Repackage that exception as something else. exception constructors have a 'cause' variant specifically for this purpose.

For example, if you use an IDE, it's broken. You can fix it. Go into the template settings and fix the problem in the 'catch exceptions' template. Instead of `e.printStackTrace();` as body of the default catch block, the correct "I dunno and I do not want to deal with this right now" catch block is:

```
} catch (SomeException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("unhandled", e);
}
```

That's 'rethrowing'.

This method's *what* is intrinsically connected to file I/O - after all, your method's signature is yelling from the rooftops, so to speak, that it does this: It has a parameter of type `File` that 'hardcodes' into the very nature of this method that it will, definitely, interact with the file system. Hence, declaring it as `throws IOException` seems correct here.

Note that your main method can, and almost always should, be declared as `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {}`.